# Firebase remote config - Conditional parameter cannot select "User propertier"

Tags: firebase-remote-config

I have added custom properties to users, like anonymousId, favoriteX and so on, but in firebase remote config ui I cannot create a condition like
`for user that has property anonymousId = qa` then set value of property to somevalue.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed the issue.

That menu is enabled only after specified `custom definitions` in firebase, where user is the scope

[image]